# regex replacing at beginning of line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

for example I have txt with content

```
qqqqaa
qqss
ss00
```

I want to replace only one q at the beginning of line, that is to get

```
qqqaa
qss
ss00
```

I tried replace `^q` in notepad++. But After I click replaceAll, I got

```
aa
ss
ss00
```

What is wrong? Is my regex wrong? What is the correct form?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nope, this is not what I want. I want to replace only one q, not replace two qs to one q

Comment: Then please update the example, it is a bit misleading.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just tried the same regex in Geany(another kind of editor) in which replace `^q` works. So I thought it is a bug or a design of notepad++?

Comment: This is happening because Notepad++ does not replace them all at once, but one after the other. So after replacing first q (when there are more than one), then the next q is now at the beginning of the line. What I would do, replace `^q` with space, then replace space in the beginning of the line with nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Notepad++ *Replace All* functionality replaces in a loop using the modified document.

The solution is to actually consume what we need to replace and keep within one regex expression like

```
^q(q*)
```

and replace with `$1`.

The pattern will find a `q` at the beginning of the line and then will capture into Group 1 zero or more occurrences of `q` after the first `q`, and in the replacement part the `$1` will insert these `q`s inside Group 1 back into the string.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor Stribiżew. regarding `Notepad++ Replace All functionality replaces in a loop`, I will open another post which maybe related.

Comment: You know, this is not the only funny thing with Notepad++ regex. E.g. `\b\w` is supposed to only match an alphanumeric or `_` after a non-word char, but it will match all `c`, `a` and `t` in `cat`. I already opened a bug for that some months ago, no feedback :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^q(.+)` and replace with `$1` if you also want to replace single q's.

Comment: The same approach as described in my question, and a bit slower, but will work, yes.